# Why does Qt use d_func() for instantiating a pointer to private data?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

Consider the following Qt class:

```
#include <QScopedPointer>

class MyClassPrivate;
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
    private:
        QScopedPointer<MyClassPrivate> d_ptr;
        Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(MyClass)
}
```

This class resembles the structure of most Qt classes that implement private implementation. The macro `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` will cause the  following expansion (as of Qt5):

```
inline MyClassPrivate* d_func()
    { return reinterpret_cast<MyClassPrivate *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); }
inline const MyClassPrivate* d_func() const
    { return reinterpret_cast<const MyClassPrivate *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); }
friend class MyClassPrivate;
```

This is confusing - why isn't `d_ptr` used directly in member functions? In other words, instead of doing this:

```
Q_D(MyClass);
d->member = 12345;
```

Why not do this?

```
d_ptr->member = 12345;
```

What is the reason for having an explicit function that (basically) just returns the `d_ptr` and incurs the overhead of an extra variable on the stack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the derived class and base class each has a Private structure, it would waste more memory, thus in Qt, the private class is also inherited, and the derived class and the base class shares one d_ptr. The problem of doing so is that the d_ptr is now of type BasePrivate.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    BasePrivate * d_ptr;
}

class Derived
{
// There is not d_ptr declared
}
```

So you can see, in the derived class, when it access d_ptr, the type is BasePrivate*. So it needs to cast d_ptr to DerivedPrivate*. The d_func function is inline, once compiled, it will always cast the d_ptr to the correct type.

[This post](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer) illustrates better than what I say here, I suggest you read it.

Comment: If none of my classes are inheriting from each other, is there any advantage to using the `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` macro then? Is inheritance the only reason for the inline methods?

Comment: @NathanOsman I think there should be no reason to use the macro if you are using two classes that are not inheriting each other. Each of them can have a individual implementation. But the fact is that in Qt, almost all the classes are inherited from the QObject class, and the inheritance can be very deep sometimes, if there is no such mechanism, it would incur a big overhead for memory.